# SQL Exception when trying to populate object explorer

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have a SQL Database in Azure.  Multiple ones actually.  I am a global admin and have created some of the databases and another developer created the others.  All of a sudden when I try to connect to them using the admin account that was created when the databases where created, I am getting the following exceptions:

```
Error connecting to '<DATABASENAME (I replaced the text here.)>'.
Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)
```

That is from SSMS.  If I try the same thing in Azure Data Studio, I connect to the database, but trying to view the tables throws an exception.

```
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
```

Also, all my connection strings in C# code work using the same account to perform CRUD operations.  So it appears that I am connecting the server, but when trying to get the metadata for the database it's failing.  I have not changed any firewall setting, I use the built in antivirus in windows 10. I have made sure that the white-listed IP in Azure is in-fact mine and it hasn't changed.  I have been googling the heck out of this all weekend and can't find a cause of solution.  I hope the issue I am having makes sense.  Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: I have uninstalled SSMS 17.9.1 and Azure Data Studio.  I then rebooted and installed SSMS 18.0 Preview 7.  I am getting the same errors.

Comment: Ok, installed SSMS 18 on another laptop and tried there.  It worked.  So it is something isolated to my laptop.  I did notice that SSMS install on new laptop did ask for a restart after install.  But, on my laptop it did not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being hard ware related on my machine.  I have replace my computer and everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Check if in Azure settings there is a rule to grant at your machine access on DB hosted in Azure space.

You can go [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/), a guide about Azure firewall rule.

Comment: yes my IP is white listed to allow access.  It was working just fine and then this weekend it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out that something on my laptop is corrupt.  When I ran SSMS on another laptop on the same network, it worked fine.  Also running SSMS in a VM on my laptop it worked.  So something is corrupt.  Just hard to find what it is, since I already uninstalled/installed.  So I will be wiping machine and starting from scratch.